# List view duplicate data

Tags: android, listview

I am using list view to populate data in the custom dialog. I am passing a List to adapter. The list has 250 different items.

The problem I have is getView method of adapter is being called only 7 times and then the data is displayed in dialog. The dialog has first 7 items repeated to fill all the 250 rows in the dialog.

I couldn't understand why the getView is called only 7 times (and also in my dialog I can see 7 items at a time.. and i need to scroll to view other items. Is there any relation between the number of elements I see and number of times the getView will be called).

Any idea why it happens. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you following the `ViewHolder` pattern?

Comment: yes, i am using holder

Comment: Humm.. weird! have you debugged your app to check what's the size of your data array size, or so (just to make sure you really don't have repeated date inside the array)?

Comment: yes,i have issue in that patter. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think `getView` is called when the item is actually displayed on the screen. When you scroll, more items become visible and `getView` will be called more times.

Comment: i am creating new row only if convertView is null otherwise I return the same row. I couldn't understand why the data is duplicated in my dialog.

Comment: first seven items are repeated for all rows(250)

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question. Can you please post your code to help me understand your problem?

Comment: sorry guys, got the problem. I have not handled the else part in viewholder pattern properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i am creating new row only if convertView is null otherwise I return the same row. I couldn't understand why the data is duplicated in my dialog"

You can try to set the data of each item every time you return from `getView` method. `convertView` is reused, you need to update the data of the `convertView` bind of. You can use `ViewHolder` to save widgets in each item.